# how to call a function after 6 digit entered in input box angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am using angular.
i have a input box after entered 6 digit i have to click the button.

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="loginData.otp" id="otp1" placeholder="OTP" >
        </label> 
        <label class="item">
         <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="otplogin" type="submit">Login</button>

  </label>
```

i have a input box after entering 6 digit i need to click the button.
how can i call function after entering 6 digit.so that i no need to click the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use $scope.$watch to watch the length of the input.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope){
    $scope.loginData = { otp: '' };

    $scope.$watch('loginData.otp.length', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newValue == 6){
             alert('Process to next level'); 
             // put your function here
        }
    });
}
```

Check out my answer in http://jsfiddle.net/Zing87/po9rxsLs/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-change` attribute, something like `ng-change="inputChanged()"`. In your controller you have

```
$scope.inputChanged = function() { 
    // Check value of $scope.loginData.otp here, example:
    if(!$scope.loginData.otp || $scope.loginData.otp.length < 5) {
        return;
    }
    // then you continue with your processing
};
```

Check the documentation for more:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

**Update:**

The currently accepted answer uses `$watch`. You should try to minimize using `$watch` in controllers (just in directives whenever possible, [an example of why](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html)).

In this question you say you are interested in the value change due to user entry, so, I think it makes sense to use the view's `change` directive, as it's a user change event.